# hook_form_alter Save $form['account']['field_first_name'] into $form['profile']['field_first_name']

Tags: forms, users

Hi I'm trying to save a field into another field in the same form when the form is submitted.

I've tried using hook_form_alter and checked for `count($form_state['input']) > 0` to save $form['account']['field_first_name'] into $form['profile']['field_first_name']

I know you may say that I can use the profile2 module. I'm already using that. I just need to figure out how to save one field value into another field when a form is submitted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! In my hook_form_alter function I added `$form['#submit'][]='my_submit';`

Then I created the `my_submit()` function.

```
function my_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if (count($form_state['input']) > 0) {
    form_state_values_clean($form_state);
    $form_state['values']['profile']['field_first_name'] = $form_state['values']['field_first_name'];
    $form_state['values']['profile']['field_last_name'] = $form_state['values']['field_last_name'];
    $form_state['values']['profile']['field_groups'] = $form_state['values']['field_groups'];

    unset($form_state['values']['field_first_name']);
    unset($form_state['values']['field_last_name']);
    unset($form_state['values']['field_groups']);
  }
}
```

The important parts of the function above to notice are `form_state_values_clean($form_state);` then I access the values through `$form_state['values']` array.

Hope this helps someone else looking to do the same functionality.